# Intel Rapid Storage alongside with Linux

Tags: partition, dual-boot

I installed Windows on an IRS NVME RAID1 volume (fake raid). The volume takes only part of the space available on the two drives.

I wish to dual boot Windows and Linux. As far as I know IRS NVME is presently not supported in Linux. In Linux I can see the two drives, with copies of the Windows partitions on each of them.

Could I create regular partitions (perhaps software RAID with mdadm) on the remainder space on the drives in order to install Linux for dual boot, or would it just result in damaging the Windows partitions on the IRS volume? Are there any precautions on how to do it properly?

Comment: Linux uses the vmd driver for NVMe drives. I have used NVMe for over a year. My new Dell with Secure Boot on & RAID mode with one drive, just works. My older system that I updated M.2 drive from SATA to NVMe drive is in AHCI mode for drives. You may need the server type drivers used for RAID, mdadm. https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347

Comment: @oldfred what do you mean by "RAID mode with one drive"? In my case I see the IRS volume and Windows partitions in it, but I see two copies of them, one of each drive, so Linux apparently doesn't recognize it as RAID1. Which is maybe OK if I don't modify the Windows partitions. My question is if I can partition the remainder of the disk safely in Linux.

Comment: Windows systems for years have had RAID or Intel RST mode, not AHCI for a single hard drive.  And there are multiple types of RAID, but the Linux mdadm driver normally works. But I have seen many users say the RAID with NVMe does not offer a lot of extra speed & breaking RAID and then having two drives is a possibility. RAID is normally for servers & is really only for uptime, and is not backup. You still need to have good backups, especially before any major system change.https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234949/install-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-with-raid-1-on-two-devices